# The paths of picture locations in python

Tags: python, image, path, cmd, pygame

I have following problem. When i am trying to open Python game files which i downloaded from internet (on the cmd), then i cant run them, because my computer doesn't find pictures which are in code. Even though the main code and pictures are in the same folder.

If i insert full paths of the pictures locations, then everything is fine, but it takes too much time, with long code.

So, my question is, how could i make my computer to open picture files, without me inserting full paths.

Thanks if anyone could help.

Comment: Where is `pygame` looking for resource files?

Comment: What is the full command you're running? What is the current working directory? What is the file structure of the script and images?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the files are called you could use something like this:

```
import os
import os.path

filename = 'name_of_your_file'
file_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
```

That should give you the full path of the file without having to enter the entire thing yourself.

You would use file_path wherever you needed the path to that particular file.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Relative Paths.

Additionally, without seeing your image loading code it is really quite hard to help you.